# How to undo change made to Python 2D array of class instances like in C++

Tags: python, c++, arrays

```
bool backtrack(int k)
{
    if (k >= bt.size())
        return true;
    int i = bt[k].first;
    int j = bt[k].second;
    // fast path - only 1 possibility
    if (cells[i][j].value)
        return backtrack(k + 1);
    auto constraints = cells[i][j].constraints;
    // slow path >1 possibility.
    // making snapshot of the state
    array<array<cell,9>,9> snapshot(cells);
    for (int v = 1; v <= 9; v++) {
        if (!constraints[v]) {
            if (set(i, j, v)) {
                if (backtrack(k + 1))
                    return true;
            }
            // restoring from snapshot,
            cells = snapshot;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How do I do the exact same thing in Python? Right now I have this but it's not working. I am making deep copy and it's still not giving the same answer.
Here cells is a 2D array of Cell instances

```
def backtrack(self, k, bt, cells):
    if k == len(bt):
        return True      
    i = bt[k][0]
    j = bt[k][1]
    if cells[i][j].value:
        return self.backtrack(k+1, bt, cells)
    constraints = list(cells[i][j].constraints)
    deepcop = copy.deepcopy(cells)
    for v in range(1, 10):        
        if not constraints[v]:
            if self.set(i, j, v, cells):
                if self.backtrack(k + 1, bt, cells):
                    return True
            cells = deepcop
    return False
```

Edit: I have added the complete functions. C++ is using global variables whereas I am passing the parameters in Python. `bt` is an arrays of pair objects in C++ and it's an array of tuples in Python.

Comment: I believe you need to deepcopy every type, since in python variables store references to stuff(think passing around pointers in c++)

Comment: Your indentation is messed up, and you have return statements outside a function body.  Did you leave out a function definition statement?

Comment: @paul Thanks. I edited the question I think it's correct now.

Answer (score 0):

The two programs are not equivalent.  In the C++ version, this line:

```
cells = snapshot;
```

replaces the object identified by the *global* variable `cells` with the object identified by the local variable `snapshot`.

In the Python version, this line:

```
cells = deepcop
```

replaces the object identified by the *local* variable `cells` with the object identified by the local variable `deepcop`.

The two languages are very similar in how they treat function arguments.  Function arguments are scoped only within the function body, and no function can ever cause an object *in the calling scope* to be replaced by a different one.  (When an argument is an object with internal state, that state can of course be changed within the function body.)

Since you are working with functions defined in a Python class (you use the `self` variable), consider making `cells` a member variable.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! Since objects are passed by reference in Python I assumed it would be equivalent to using a global/static variable. This was for a problem with multiple test cases and a `Solution` class so had to create a new `Solution.cells` variable when I was done with `cells` because all the test cases were using the `Solution`'s static `cells`